# Prevent Ember Data bulk commit for single item?

Tags: ember-data

I need Ember Data to update one of my models in bulk. So I set

```
  bulkCommit: true
```

in the `DS.RESTAdapter`. But now it even uses bulk commits for updates to a single record!

This is very unexpected behaviour.

So how do I modify Ember Data to only use bulk commits when *more than 1 item* is committed?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've done now:

```
 updateRecords: function(store, type, records) {
    var arr;
    arr = records.list;
    if (arr.length === 1) {
      return this.updateRecord(store, type, arr[0]);
    } else {
      return this._super(store, type, records);
    }
  }
```

This checks if `records` consists of a single item and calls `updateRecord` then.

`createRecords` and `deleteRecords` are changed accordingly.